# Kings and Roman Emperors puzzle.

Tags: probability

So between AD 138 and 293 there were 15 British Kings and also 15 Roman Emperors as detailed here.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CurRH8W4e_g

Assuming this information is correct; namely that each King listed came to power in the same year as the Roman Emperor.. What is the probability that this is merely a coincidence?

Additionally excluding King Gwrgan which seems to translate directly, what is the probability that these King / Emperor pairs had names beginning with the same letters?

Comment: Please show you have made some work.

Comment: Roughly 1000 trillion to 1, not including the similar names?

Comment: The probability is much less than the probability that someone doing some imaginative back-filling of blank spaces when writing their list of kings decided to do some heavy borrowing from a list of Roman emperors they had lying about.